# Why is the offsetof macro necessary?

Tags: c, struct, offsetof

I am new to the C language and just learned about structs and pointers.

My question is related to the `offsetof` macro I recently saw. I know how it works and the logic behind that.

In the `<stddef.h>` file the definition is as follows:

```
#define offsetof(type,member) ((unsigned long) &(((type*)0)->member))
```

My question is, if I have a struct as shown below:

```
struct test {
    int field1:
    int field2:
};

struct test var;
```

Why cannot I directly get the address of `field2` as:

```
char * p = (char *)&var;
char *addressofField2 = p + sizeof(int);
```

Rather than writing something like this

```
field2Offset = offsetof (struct test, field2);
```

and then adding offset value to var's starting address?

Is there any difference? Is using `offsetof` more efficient?

Comment: If you are new to C, hands off `offsetof` and the like. You will not need it for normal programming, but only advanced features a beginner will very likely mess up. - Nop offence, but a very well meant warning!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C compiler will often add extra padding bits or bytes between members of a `struct` in order to improve efficiency and keep integers word-aligned (which in some architectures is required to avoid [bus errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error#Unaligned_access) and in some architectures is required to avoid efficiency problems). For example, in many compilers, if you have this `struct`:

```
struct ImLikelyPadded {
    int x;
    char y;
    int z;
};
```

you might find that `sizeof(struct ImLikelyPadded)` is 12, not 9, because the compiler will insert three extra padding bytes between the end of the one-byte `char y` and the word-sized `int z`. This is why `offsetof` is so useful - it lets you determine where things really are even factoring in padding bytes and is highly portable.

Comment: As an addition, the only reason the implementation gets away with UB in the macro is that it *is* the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike arrays, memory layout of struct is not always contiguous. Compiler may add extra bytes, in order to align the memory. This is called `padding`.

Because of padding, it us difficult to find location of member manually. This is also why we always use sizeof to find struct size.

`offsetof` macro let you find out the distance, offset, of a member of struct from the starting position of the struct.

One intelligent use of `offsetof` is seen in Linux kernel's `container_of` macro. This macro let you find out starting position of node given the address of member in a generic inclusive doubly linked list.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the other answers, padding is one of the reasons. I won't repeat what was already said about it.

Another good reason to use the `offsetof` macro and not manually compute offsets is that you only have to write it once. Imagine what happens if you need to change the type of `field1` or insert or remove one or more fields in front of `field2`. Using your hand-crafted calculation you have to find and change all its occurrences. Missing one of them will produce mysterious bugs that are difficult to find.

The code written using `offsetof` doesn't need any update in this situation. The compiler takes care of everything on the next compilation.

Even more, the code that uses `offsetof` is more clear. The macro is standard, its functionality is [documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof). A fellow programmer that reads the code understands it immediately. It's not that easy to understand what the hand-crafted code attempts.